# Matrix operations that preserve the nullspace of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Context:** Let $A$ be matrix of nullity $> 0.$ I want to *compute* the nullspace of $A.$ But in certain cases, it's easier to transform $A$ into another matrix, then compute the nullspace of the resulting matrix, given that the transformation preserves the nullspace. For example: $\mbox{nullspace}(A) = \mbox{nullspace}(A^t A).$

**My Question:** In addition to multiplying $A$ by its transpose, what are the other matrix operations that preserve the nullspace of $A$?

Comment: Have you heard of [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A \to SA$ where $S$ is an invertible matrix, or more generally a matrix such that the intersection of the nullspace of $S$ and the column space of $A$ is $\{0\}$ (this includes the case $S = A^t$, as well as the elementary row operations).